# How to generate separate pages for each group?

Tags: jasper-reports

Story:
Two Domain Objects:

```
class JasperProject {
    private String ...
}

class JasperProjectGroup {
    private String ...
    private List<JasperProject> ...
}
```

Code for Jasper:

```
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<JasperProjectGroup> groups = buildGroups();
        parameters.put("groups", groups);

        InputStream jasperReportInputStream = ProjectStatusReportGenerator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                        PROJECT_STATUS_JASPER_REPORT_FILENAME);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportInputStream, parameters,
                        new JREmptyDataSource());

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);

        return outputStream.toByteArray();
```

**I want to create a pdf report with tables which each group table on each separate page (e.g. table for group 1 on page1, table for group 2 on page2).
However, when I pass the groups as parameter to Jasper template, it display just one table contains all the groups on the pdf report.**

XML code for jrxml

First xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="timesheets" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="groups" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="800" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="515" height="800"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[(new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{groups}))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("projectgroup.jasper")]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Second template (projectgroup.jrxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="projectgroup" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <subDataset name="TableDataset1">
        <field name="projectName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="bookedHours" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="predictedHours" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="burnedHours" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="percentageComplete" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="bookedHoursBurned" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <field name="jasperProjectStatusReports" class="java.util.List"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="515" height="50"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[(new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{jasperProjectStatusReports}))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("projectgroup_table.jasper")]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Third template xml (projectgroup_table.jasper):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="projectgroup_table" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="groupName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="projectName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="bookedHours" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="predictedHours" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="burnedHours" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="percentageComplete" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="bookedHoursBurned" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#006700"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{groupName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#006700"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Booked]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#006700"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Predicted]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#006700"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Burned]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="400" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#006700"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Complete]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="500" y="0" width="95" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#006700"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Booked Burned]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{projectName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="0" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bookedHours}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{predictedHours}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{burnedHours}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="400" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{percentageComplete}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="500" y="1" width="95" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bookedHoursBurned}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Are there any ideas about that? thanks.

Comment: Can I ask you why you have multiple nested reports?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. If you expand the detail field by using ireprt... by this when once your one group got printed there will be no space for other group, so that next group will be on next page.

Its jasper report's built-in functionality.